# Event listerner in loop

Tags: javascript, html

I've added an click event to a checkbox so that when it's clicked the class of another element is checked.
This is in a loop, for some reason it only works on the first line of code.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

PHP:

```
while ($row_list = mysqli_fetch_array($res_list)) {
    $i++;
    echo '<div class="checkbox">' .
         '<label><input type="checkbox" id="del" name="del" value="ja">Ja ik wil deze toolbox verwijderen</label>' .
         '</div>';
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#submit_delete').classList.remove('disabled')
});
```

Comment: Would you mind showing how you are using the loop?

Answer (score 0):

you need a loop and a collection of results, using `querySelectorAll`

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'), 
  elm=> elm.addEventListener('click', () =>
  document.querySelector('#submit_delete').classList.remove('disabled')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

As dandavis noted, `document.querySelector` will only get the first hit. If you want to get several results, you need to use `document.querySelectorAll`. That will return a `NodeList`, which you can turn into an array with `Array.from`.

```
while ($row_list = mysqli_fetch_array($res_list)) { 
  $i++;
  echo '
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="del" value="ja">
        Ja ik wil deze toolbox verwijderen
      </label>
    </div>
  ';
}

<script>
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('#submit_delete');
const checkboxes = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'));
checkboxes.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () =>
  deleteButton.classList.remove('disabled')
))
</script>
```

Comment: Since you're using `[].from`, you can just pass your `forEach()` callback as a 2nd argument to `.from()` and it will execute on each element, exactly the same as your forEach does, but without the stray variable...

Comment: Probably not how I would've implemented it, but I like to be a bit more wordy when I write examples like this. What's obvious to you and me might not be to the next guy reading this answer :)